# HTML pattern does't work even with correct regular expression

Tags: regex, html

Regular expression: `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]))`

Input string: `qwer1Q`

The input string above pass the validation if you check it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

However, if you include the regex in a html `pattern` attribute and try to validate the same string again, it shall not pass:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" 
      pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]))">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the pattern matches (and *consumes*) the *entire* string because the [HTML5 pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) regex is anchored by default.

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" 
      pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*` pattern will be turned into `^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*)$` and it will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?=.*\d)` - a positive lookahead check to make sure there is at least 1 digit
  - `(?=.*[A-Z])` - a positive lookahead check to make sure there is at least 1 uppercase letter
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars, greedily, up to the end of string
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: IMPORTANT: To clarify, the pattern must CAPTURE your entire input, not just match it. This is why you need the .*

Comment: @Ciabaros It is not capturing here, it is *consuming*. To capture, you need to use capturing groups, and there are none here.

Comment: My pattern is very simple: `[A-Za-z]{2,30}` no forward slashed and the quantifier is enough, right? It has the `required` attribute and the input field still accepts characters like 1,2,3,@#$%^... I mean they are VALIDATED right, why? It happens in my local environment. I use Dreamweaver and at coding I also test with Brackets. One note: I am working with local server. My HTML contact form is saved as php. Does it have to do with client validation isues?

Comment: @limakid Please read the `pattern` attribute docs. The regex there does not limit the *user input*, the validation happens *on submit*. You can type anything there if you do not provide an extra coding.