# Html5 input pattern can not handle positive lookaheads correctly

Tags: regex, html, input, regex-lookarounds

I want 2 regex mathing input string at one time:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?=first match of whole string)(?=second match of whole string)" />
```

In the output I want only the RegEx `/^(?=first match of whole string)(?=second match of whole string)$/`.

I saw similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764480/html-pattern-doest-work-even-with-correct-regular-expression/43764517), but there must to be added `.*` at the end of initial `pattern` value, - it does **not** feet for my purpose.

Thanx

Comment: `pattern="(?=first match of whole string)(?=second match of whole string).*"` will fit your purpose exactly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanx for answering, the second RegEx I have is `(?=\+([0-9]\s?){7,15})` - it is the length validation at some point (but just for count of numbers in string). And it does not work if I append `.*`, I will still can type more than 15 numbers in string

Comment: That is not the issue with `.*`. You just missed `$`: `(?=\+([0-9]\s?){7,15}$)` - and then it is still a dupe of [Regex - Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree